# removing a pipe sign from text with javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have some text that I am rendering using underscore and it contains pipe character that I am trying to remove.

This is what I have tried

```
<script type="text/html" id="activityDescriptionTmpl">
    <%=  formatInput(container.CurrentActivity.ProcessActivityDescription) %>
</script>
```

this is what the text looks like

```
This is the text with pipe character at the end|
```

This id a javascript function I created

```
formatInput = function (input) {
        var arr = [];
        var finalInput = '';
        if (input.indexOf('|') > 0) {
            arr = input.split('|');
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if ($.trim(arr[i]).length > 0)
                    finalInput += $.trim(arr[i]) + '<br />';
            }
        }
        else {
            finalInput = input;
        }
        return finalInput;
    };
```

But in this case I get the error`cannot read property 'indexOf' undefined`

Is there perhaps a better way of just removing this pipe character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `newInput = input.replace("|", "");`

http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/sGKf3/